# Split last commit and modify intermediate commits while updating working dir at each step

Tags: git

I want to split the most recent commit C into multiple commits C# (# = 1, 2, ... etc.). However each intermediate commit C# cannot be directly done with the corresponding partial changes in C, but they have to be modified to some extent to "make sense". Additionally, to determine if a commit C# "makes sense" the working directory needs to be in a state that represents this commit such that the corresponding changes can be made **before** committing, without losing the content of the final commit C.

In my case, i have the following:

- I have a commit of some code with too many changes that I want to split, because
- the program is bugged after the commit, but not before, and there are too many new features for easy debugging
- I cannot simply remove some features without breaking the others, so I have to edit each feature before doing a 'partial commit' of it
- to make sure a commit makes sense, I check if the program compiles with only this one new feature
- (obviously) I do not want to lose the code for all the other features so I can easily get back to the original commit C

---

So my question is a combination of

- How do I split the latest commit and create multiple new commits with only parts of the changes?
- How do I edit files (in the working dir) in between the new commits without losing the changes that make up the original one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably many solutions, I tried to find a "straightforward" one. In particular there should be no ugly temporary commits, no need to resolve conflicts and no need to always start editing files from the state of commit C. I will call commit B the one before C.

To do this I create patch files with `git diff` and apply them as needed with `git apply`. In detail:

- first, to discard the last commit and keep the changes in the working dir

  ```
  git reset HEAD~
  ```
- for convenience ignore patch files

  ```
  echo "*.diff" >> .gitignore
  ```
- now, before editing a file, create a patch so we can go back to the version from C. Files that did not exist in B need to be added to the index first (otherwise the patch will be empty!) like this:

  ```
  git add -N file    #not needed for files that exist in B
  ```
- create the patch and set the working dir version to the one from B

  ```
  git diff file >> file.diff
  git checkout file
  ```
- repeat these steps for every file that was changed from B to C. Now to apply partial changes to both the index **and** the working dir. First, for files that did not exist in B, we have to remove them again (or just do not checkout the file before)

  ```
   rm file      #not needed for files that exist in B
  ```
- Then stage the partial changes and update the patch accordingly:

  ```
   git apply file.diff
   rm file.diff
   git add -i                  #interactively stage only partial changes
   git diff file >> file.diff
   git checkout file
  ```

---

With the steps above I can stage partial changes while always having the version that corresponds to the partial commit in the working dir (not the C version!). Instead, the C version is "saved" in patches. With some additional steps, I can edit the versions of the files of the intermediate commits.

- edit `file`, and again create patches, but these have to be applied in reverse later. Name these patches e.g. with increasing number <#> for each edit

  ```
  git diff file >> file.reverse<#>.diff
  git add file
  ```
- these steps can be repeated for each edit, creating an additional reverse<#>.diff each time.
- after N edits a patch that turns this latest version back to the C version can be created by applying the patches in the correct order

  ```
  git apply -R file.reverse<N>.diff
  git apply -R file.reverse<N-1>.diff
  #...
  git apply -R file.reverse1.diff
  git apply file.diff
  rm file*.diff
  git diff file >> file.diff
  git checkout file
  ```

Again, the working dir version is now the version of the current intermediate commit, and the patch `file.diff` can be applied to get back to the C version.

---

Note: I created the question + answer because I am not fluent in git and I'm sure I will have forgotten how I did this the next time .. There were some similar answers I found but nothing that solved my exact problem so maybe someone else will find this useful.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely use `git reset --soft` to handle the situation. So, say, you have your branch, it's called featA. You want to create a few intermediate revisions between featA and featA~1. This is what I would do:

```
git checkout -b temp featA # create branch temp from featA, check it out
git reset soft --HEAD~1 # put all changes between featA and feat~1 in index, ready to be commited.
# at this time you go to your files and edit them the way you want them to be on the first "new" revision. Revert changes at will, featA won't move no matter what
# when you are done, add everything to index
git commit -m "First new revision"

# now, for every new revision you want to create:
git checkout --detach featA
git reset --soft temp
# same thing.... set the files you want it for the following revision
# add to index
git commit "a new revision"
git branch -f temp # move temp pointer

# then in the _last_ revision, when you want this new revision to resemble featA
git checkout featA
git reset --soft temp
git commit -m "Final new revision"
```

Alternatively, from the second part of the recipe (2nd intermediate revisions and plus) it can be handled by comparing with tempA so that you bring over changes little by little instead of going back to full featA for each new revision (adjusting code to make sense, as you said in the question).